# Variable name as string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment

Is there a way to retrieve a variable's name in JavaScript without it being part of an object? Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
var obj = {//Declared in a global scope
    init:function(){
        var var1 = /*value from input*/;
        var var2 = /*value from input*/;

        doCode({name:/*variable name as a string, "var1"*/,val:var1});
        doCode({name:/*variable name as a string, "var2"*/,val:var2});
        function checkNumber(args){
            if(typeof args.val != 'number')
                console.error("Error variable '"+arg.name+"' is not a number!");
            else
                console.log("Variable '"+arg.name+"' is a number!");
        }
    }
}
obj.init();
```

Comment: Except in very specific circumstances, like when the calling function only calls `checkNumber` once with one variable as its argument or the value is unique among some object you can access from the function, the answer is “no”. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: In what scope is `var1` and `var2` declared ?

Comment: How about this[variableName] ?

Comment: @san.chez - depends on the scope, and what `this` really is, that's why I asked ?

Comment: @adeneo `this` is an object declared in a global scope, editing my code to reflect that
@minitech for Error login purposes

Comment: @PhilippeTrépanier: Keep them all in one object, pass the name. Alternatively, pass the field and create a `data-label` attribute or something, then check `arg.value` and use `arg.dataset.label`. (Note that your `typeof` check probably doesn’t perform as intended if this is user input…)

Comment: @minitech I used typeof to shorten my original code, it would appear that keeping them in an object is the only way, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```
var foo = 'bar'
var fooname
for (var i in window) {
  if (window[i] == foo) fooname = i
}
alert(fooname) // alerts 'foo'
```

**upd** Of course, that have some restrictions, for example you can't have two variables with same content, but it is the only way I still found.

Comment: I wont use this in a global scope but with an object instead, thank you! +1 and correct.